# Grpc.Core updated to 2.23, System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: Void Grpc.Core.ClientBase`1..ctor(Grpc.Core.Channel)

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

After update [Grpc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/) to 2.23 getting

**Method not found: 'Void Grpc.Core.ClientBase`1..ctor(Grpc.Core.Channel)'**

in

```
public MyClient(IConfiguration config, ILogger<MyClient> logger)
{
    var thisConfig = config.GetGRPCConfigObject();
    var channel = new Channel($"{thisConfig.HostName}:{thisConfig.Port}", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    this.Client = new MyPackage.ServiceClient(channel); // exception here
    this.Logger = logger;
}
```

how to construct the ServiceClient in 2.23?

Comment: Did you regenerate your `MyPackage.ServiceClient` with gRPC 2.23? Did you rebuild afterwards? It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: thanks for a comment, @JonSkeet. MyPackage comes from Azure DevOps as a nuget package. I have the last version, I supposed it to be rebuilded. I use [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) to create MyPackage. Will try to build explicitly.

Comment: I suggest you check the dependencies in the NuGet package. If it depends on Grpc.Core.Apis (or similar) 1.x, then it's incompatible with 2.x, I'm afraid.

Comment: I depend on Google.Protobuf 3.8.0 and Grpc.Core 2.23. In MyPackage I use Grpc.Tools 1.22.0.

Comment: It's still not clear to me where MyPackage comes from - if it's from NuGet, you shouldn't need Grpc.Tools at all yourself, although I'd strongly encourage you to generate the code using the same major version you want to consume. Or by "from Azure DevOps" do you mean you're building it yourself, but it's being served as a NuGet package to your application? If it's the latter, again you need to clarify which version of Grpc you're *building* against.

Comment: Package constructed by Azure pipeline (I'm building it myself with `dotnet pack` command).

Comment: Right, so what does that project depend on? My guess is that it depends on Grpc.Core 1.22.0 or similar. Again, a [mcve] would make it a lot easier to help you without guesswork.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. Problem solved. Regarding your question: MyPackage depend on Google.Protobuf 3.8.0, Grpc.Core 2.23, Grpc.Tools 1.22.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem **updating** both **Grpc.Core and Grpc.Tools** to version **2.24**.